# NSPredicate filtering

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have the following json object is stored as `self.pElements`. I have a `search bar` to be used to filter items based on the `name`.

```
[
 {"id":"1","name":"Baked Chicken","category":"1","price":"5.49"},
 {"id":"2","name":"Beef Kabob","category":"2","price":"5.49"},
 {"id":"3","name":"Beef Gyro","category":"1","price":"5.49"},
 {"id":"4","name":"Lamb Gyro","category":"4","price":"5.49"} 
]
```

I try to filter by `name` as follows, but it always returns me null. even I type just `Beef`, nothing has been returned

```
pTempElements =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.pElements filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", self.searchBar.text]]];
```

Comment: None of the "name" values are equal to "Beef".

Comment: `name = ` => it means a "perfect match". you may want to replace it with `name BEGINSWITH[c]` (the [c] being for case insenstive in order to "beef" be okay.

Comment: could you please give a small example? What if user types `Gyro` only?

Comment: @hotspring Do you want show the names that contains Gyro only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter for strings that contain the search string, use `contains[cd]`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", searchText];
```

For list of the sorts of string comparisons one can do, see [Predicate Format String Syntax: String Comparisons](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868) in the *Predicate Programming Guide.*